# jQuery: A vertical list of imgs/text that rotates by sliding (first img will go to last, etc)

Tags: jquery, slider, slideshow

I've been trying every slideshow script I can think of, but I can't come up with a way to do this:

I have a vertical list of images with some text that I want to slide up(or down, not important)- so the first item would go to the end of the list and the second would slide up, and so on. *All list items are displayed at all times though, so it wouldn't be just a few displayed and then scrolls* I hope that makes sense, I thought it would be straightforward. I'd like it to auto scroll/slide too. I'd really appreciate any help, I've spent quite a while struggling with this.

Here's a primitive text representation for clarity:

list li's:

```
[1]
[2]
[3]
[4]
[5]
```

becomes:

```
[2]
[3]
[4]
[5]
[1]
```

and loops.

<sub>Update: I got it to partially work with jCarousel: http://jsfiddle.net/Y9Esg/</sub>

<sub>The only issues are that it still shows part of the img at the top after it scrolls, which should be on the end. And that the list seems to keep growing? It should only be long enough for the 10 items. Hmm.</sub>

Comment: Do you want to write this, or would you be willing to use a library?

Comment: Totally fine with a library, thanks

Comment: here's another one as well
http://bxslider.com/examples/vertical-slideshow
$('.bxslider').bxSlider({
  mode: 'vertical',
  slideMargin: 5
});

Answer (score 0):

Try jCarousel: http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/examples/static_vertical.html

You can make it vertical and loop around with a few settings.

```
jQuery('#mycarousel').jcarousel({
    vertical: true,
    scroll: 1, 
    wrap: 'circular'
});
```

**Edit 1**

You need to leave in the following height and overflow css to fix the height:

**CSS**

```css
.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-container-vertical {
    width: 75px;
    height: 850px; // This fixes the height
    padding: 40px 20px;
}

.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-clip {
    overflow: hidden; // This prevents the overflow
}

.jcarousel-skin-tango .jcarousel-clip-vertical {
    width:  75px;
    height: 850px; // This fixes the height
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Y9Esg/2/)**

Comment: @Brian - I've updated my answer to fix your height and overflow problem.